# Substitution Cipher Verification

Tags: python, python-3.x, encryption

I am tasked to write a function that returns whether two strings are [substitution ciphers](https://levelup.gitconnected.com/substitution-encoder-and-solver-in-python-19984a6b8d5d) of each other. It is assumed that one isn't given a key. The output is expected to return True or False.

Here is what I have written so far on this (borrowed from a CodeFights question). The idea is to append the counts of each element in the string and add it to the `string1count` and `string2count` variables. Then, compare the counts at each index, and if they are not equal, we can assume that it is not a valid substitution cipher since each element in the array needs to have the same number of corresponding of characters in order to be a substitution cipher.

```
def isSubstitutionCipher(string1, string2):
    string1count = []
    string2count = []
    for i in range(0,len(string1)):
        string1count.append(string1.count(string1[i]))
    for i in range(0,len(string2)):
        string2count.append(string2.count(string2[i]))
    
    for i in range(0,len(string1count)):
        if string1count.count(string1count[i])!=string2count.count(string1count[i]):
            return False
    
    return True
```

**Does anyone else have other proposals on how to solve this very general question / problem statement?**

Comment: Please don't make more work for other people by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA 4.0 license](//creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/), for Stack Exchange to distribute that content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By Stack Exchange policy, the non-vandalized version of the post is the one which is distributed. Thus, any vandalism will be reverted. If you want to know more about deleting a post please see: [How does deleting work?](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you could try to re-create the subsitution:

```
def isSubstitutionCipher(string1, string2):

    if len(string1) != len(string2):
        return False

    subst = {}
    for c1, c2 in zip(string1, string2):
        if c1 in subst:
            if c2 != subst[c1]:
                return False
        else:
            if c2 in subst.values():
                return False
            subst[c1] = c2
    return True
```

for all the characters you have already seen, make sure the substitution matches. for the new ones: store them in the substitution and make sure they are not already a substitution target.

this will return `False` at the first character that does not match.

Comment: @Chris thanks for spotting that! should be fixed.

Comment: Thank you @hiro protagonist! So basically, this utilizes a hashmap where time and space complexity would be O(n) and O(n)? Since we would at worst case, iterate over the entire string only once. And since we are storing each of the characters into the hashmap, it'll be O(n) where n is the number of characters in the input string?

Comment: yes, that's right.
there might be some speedup keeping a `set` of the values that are already in `subst`. but if n is the length of the input strings, this is still O(n).
the algorithm will break early if a character is wrong...

Answer (score 2):

Here is a variation on hiro's excellent answer:

```
def is_sub(s,t):
    if len(s) != len(t):return False
    d = dict(zip(s,t))
    return t == ''.join(d[c] for c in s)
```

Comment: Thank you John! Very readable shortcut answer! I may borrow this one to make it elegant.

Answer (score 1):

We can use [word patterns](https://inventwithpython.com/hacking/chapter18.html) to check if one string is the ciphertext of another.

- word pattern: first letter gets the number 0 and the first occurrence of each different letter after that gets the next number.
- advantage is this has O(n) complexity

**Code**

```
def isSubstitutionCipher(s1, s2):
    def word_pattern(s):
        ' Generates word pattern of s '
        seen, pattern = {}, []
        for c in s:
            seen.setdefault(c, len(seen))
            pattern.append(seen[c])

        return pattern
    
    return word_pattern(s1) == word_pattern(s2) # related by ciphertext if same word patterns
```

**Test**
'

```
print(isSubstitutionCipher('banana', 'cololo')) # Output: True
print(isSubstitutionCipher('dog', 'cat')        # Output: True
print(isSubstitutionCipher('banana', 'cololl')  # Output: False
```

Comment: This was very clever @DarryIG, thank you for sharing this! Woudn't Hiro Protagonist's answer also be of O(n) time and space complexity since he is using a hashmap/dictionary? And we would be only iterating through the input string at most 1 iteration?